# Destructor in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

what is the event that is run when we go to another page. is it unload ?

```
Protected Sub Edit_Unload(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Unload

End Sub
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that any event will run.

Comment: And, as for a "destructor", the _finalizer_ for your page instance often runs before your user even sees the page. Remember that a page instance only lasts for the life of one http request. Even postbacks for the same page in the same session are handled by different instances. A page instance runs the page lifecycle to generate the html sent to the browser. Once this html is ready and transmitted, the page instance can be collected by the GC. Sometimes this happens before the time the browser can even render the response to the display.

Comment: Navigation to another page happens on the client side, not the server side.  Once you see the page in your browser, the server is no longer involved.  There are no server-side events associated with navigating from one page to another unless you use some sort of server-side links, like a `LinkButton`.  Even then, you can't control a user simply typing a different url into their browser and bypassing the server redirect altogether.

Answer (score 3):

`Unload` occurs at the end of the request<sup>*</sup>.  It doesn't have anything to do with navigating to other pages.  Pages are "loaded" and "unloaded" all over the course of a single request; the only reason it appears otherwise is the magic that the Web Forms stuff does behind the scenes.

If you want to see whether this is a new load or a postback, the Page class has an `IsPostBack` property that's true when something in the page triggers a postback to that same page.  If it's false, then this is a new request and should be treated appropriately.

Other than that, i'm not aware of a way to tell when someone specifically goes to *another* page (as opposed to just refreshing the current page), other than tracking the last page visited in the session.

<sup>* (It's defined as the last event in the page's life cycle, but might not fire if the request is terminated prematurely for any reason.  Redirects and transfers are prime examples.)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

`Unload` is the last event in the [ASP.NET Page Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Raised for each control and then for the page. In controls, use this
>   event to do final cleanup for specific controls, such as closing
>   control-specific database connections. For the page itself, use this
>   event to do final cleanup work, such as closing open files and
>   database connections, or finishing up logging or other
>   request-specific tasks.

When redirecting to another page, however, this method may not be called.

Comment: What does this have to do with navigating to other pages?

Comment: @mellamokbtheWise Ah, seems I misread.  I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This link may be of use to you: [Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Although you can't rely on events running this is a good guide to show what order (and when) they run.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to capture the event when a page leaves, you can use javascript to call a server method.  Although this works, it doesnt seem like you can halt the process in server code.  Check out my last thread I started:

[preventing page from being redirected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205548/preventing-page-from-being-redirected)

In it, I do post an example of how to use javascript to detect the page is about to leave and call a server method before that happens.